# Cutting many lines (as rivers) that are outside of a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip

I would like to extract only the vector lines, that represents rivers in my case, inside a polygon. I tried to use the intersection and clipping from QGIS, but couldn't do it. [image]

Any help?

Comment: Do your river layer and polygon layer have the same CRS?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same CRS. I could delete manually, but I suppose it must have a tool to do it automatically..

Comment: Clipping (`Vector > Geoprocessing tools`) should work if your layers have the same CRS. Alternatively, you can try OGR clipping tool ("Clip vectors by polygon", in the processing toolbox).